# Compute cosine similarity spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, cosine-similarity

How to compute cosine similarity between 2 Spark Vector. I am using the new ml package.

Spark 2.1.1

**EDIT:**

Spark provide RowMatrix which can be used to compute similarity but it accepts `mllib.vector` not an `ml.vector`.

Is there a way to convert Vectors from the different packages?
Is there an implementation that uses `ml.vector`?

Comment: You could create an UDF which takes the two vectors as input and make the calculations there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to convert from an `mllib` vector to an `ml` vector is to use the `Vectors.fromML` method, see [Vectors documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Vectors.html#fromML(org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector)). Example:

```
val mlVector = org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors.dense((Array(1.0,2.0,3.0)))
println(mlVector.getClass())

val mllibVector = org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.fromML(mlVector)
println(mllibVector.getClass())
```

Gives an output:

```
class org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector
class org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector
```

Comment: That is what I needed thanks. And to go from ```mllib.Vector``` to ```ml.Vector``` just use ```asML()``` from the ```mllib.Vector``` instance directly.